# Polyhedron and Euler's formula

Tags: geometry

I have the following question:

**Suppose a polyhedron without tunnels has 90 edges, and 60 vertices. How many faces does it have? Briefly justify your answer.**

So I know from Euler's formula that f+v-e=2.

Hence, I get that f+60-90=2 and so f=32.

But how do I justify my answer? As in, what do I need to justify?

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you have to justify that the polyhedron is convex? Cause if it isn't then the formula doesn't hold.

Comment: Depends on whether the "justification" allows use of Euler's formula.

Comment: @coffeemath well it doesn't say anything about that.. but if I'm not allowed to use Euler's formula by any chance, is there any other way to do it though?

Comment: Justification? How about a paper model of  [Truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) or even a soccer ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many situations, “Euler's formula says so” would be sufficient justification. It demonstrates that you didn't guess, didn't do some brute force computation, but instead knew suitable tools and how to apply them. In other situations, taking that formula for granted would be insufficient, and you might have to justify why the formula holds. And in between these two there is a range where you would need to closely examine that all the precondidtions of Euler's formula hold. In particular that the polyhedron is a topological sphere (genus 0), which sounds like it should be identical to the no tunnels property you quoted.